# How to load HTML into a single div using tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had script setup to toggle show/hide divs on a page with menu items.

However I wanted to load external HTML into one of them and was running into issues.

Now I am wanting to just having the menu items load external HTML into a single div.

I can't seem to make it work though and I want to have a menu like this:

```
<div id="topmenu">
<a href="#" >Home</a>
<a href="#" >Videos</a>
<a href="#" >Follow</a>
<a href="#" >Contact</a>
</div>
```

Each item loads a different HTML into a div like this using jQuery:

```
<article>
<div id="bodycontent">
...
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Not enough information given which is the one that gets data externally. Always show what you have tried

Comment: Ive tried so much from online searches that im to the point where I just want to redo it clean from scratch however the best way is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add or means to say load external html then you need to add some java scrip.Let take your example.

```
    <div id="topmenu">
<a href="#" id='homeTab'>Home</a>
<a href="#" id='videoTab'>Videos</a>
<a href="#" id='followTab'>Follow</a>
<a href="#" id='contactTab'>Contact</a>
</div>
```

See I've added individual id to each now you need to call a load function of js

```
$("#homeTab").on('click',function(){
    //firstly clear html part
    $('#bodycontent').html('');
    $('#bodycontent').load('hometab.html');//put your exact loaction of html file in my case I'm assume both are in same folder.
});
```

That's it all  done you can do like this.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Ok, so I would need to do, in this example, 4 different instances of the below code with each id & url?

Comment: $("#homeTab").on('click',function(){
    //firstly clear html part
    $('#bodycontent').html('');
    $('#bodycontent').load('hometab.html');//put your exact loaction of html file in my case I'm assume both are in same folder.
});

Comment: Sorry im new to stackoverflow so Im not sure how to edit or delete comments

Comment: I'll suggest you do some R&D by your own or take help from some senior.
I wrote the exact what you want.
Please not load only works on server means to say when it is running on local host etc.